# get first character of a string from a string vector

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stl

how to get the first character or how to get a character by index from a string in a string vector while iterating through that vector.
Here's my code:

```
vector<string>::iterator i=vec.begin();
    while(i!=vec.end()){
        if(i[0]==ch)
            cout<<"output";
    }
```

it's giving the error:

no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_string' and 'char')|

Comment: instead of your `while` loop use range based `for`, e.g. `for( const string& s : vec ) { if( s.length() > 0 && s[0] == ch )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
vector<string>::iterator i=vec.begin();
    while(i!=vec.end()){
        if(i[0][0] == ch)
            cout<<"output";
        ++i;
    }
```

`i[0]` returns the whole string pointed to by iterator i while `i[0][0]` returns the first character of the string even if the string is empty (in this case the value will be '\0'). :)

But you could write simpler

```
for ( const std::string &s : vec )
{
    if ( s[0] == ch ) cout << "output";
}
```

If you want to use some index that can have any value then the code could look like

```
vector<string>::iterator i=vec.begin();
    while(i!=vec.end()){
        if( index < i[0].size() && i[0][index] == ch)
            cout<<"output";
        ++i;
    }
```

Or

```
for ( const std::string &s : vec )
{
    if ( index < s.size() && s[index] == ch ) cout << "output";
}
```

Comment: I would say `(*i)` rather than `i[0]`. Similarly, `i->size()`.

Comment: @Hurkyl  I showed the correct syntax and semantic when expression i[0] is used.:)

Comment: You are missing `++i;` when using `while` syntax

Comment: @Jerome L It is not me.:) It is the author of the thread who missed ++i. I simply copied his code that to show the correct expression.:)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing a loop here at all, I'd use a standard algorithm. For example, to display all the strings (one per line) that start with the specified letter, you could use something like this:

```
std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
             [ch](std::string const &s) { return s[0] == ch; });
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the string at index `k` of the vector, the following code should work:

```
vector<string>::iterator i = vec.begin();
while (i != vec.end())
{
  if (i - vec.begin() == k)
    cout << (*i) << endl;
  ++i;
}
```

To get the character from that string, you can dereference at the appropriate position.

Comment: Am I missing something here, or could you have just written `vec[k]` instead of this entire block of code?

Comment: This does not answer the question. All this does it print out the kth string in the vector in a roundabout and inefficient way. It is equivalent to `cout << vec[k] << endl;`

Comment: True that. However, I felt that the person might have had some other uses besides a simple dereferencing, and was giving this query as a sample. So, I thought best to use the loop as he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is an *iterator through your sequence*, not an *element of your sequence*. `i` is like a pointer; you need to do `*i` to get the element the iterator is pointing at. e.g. `(*i)[0]` is the first character of the string that `i` points to (assuming it is nonempty, of course — if it is empty, then this is undefined behavior and all sorts of horrible things can happen).

Also, you seem to have forgotten to actually iterate through your sequence; e.g. advancing with `++i` at the end of every iteration.

Unless you specifically need to work with iterators, though, you should probably prefer something more like

```
for(std::string &s : vec) {
    // do something with s
}
```

(or more simply, `auto &s : vec`)